# Notify any unencrypted Amazon RDS databases or Amazon EBS volumes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I was looking to implement a solution to detect and notify when following event happens:

1. Unencrypted RDS storage is created
2. Unencrypted EBS volume is created

Could some one help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AWS Config Rules](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/evaluate-config_use-managed-rules.html):

> AWS Config provides **AWS managed rules**, which are predefined, customizable rules that AWS Config uses to evaluate whether your AWS resources comply with common best practices. For example, you could use a managed rule to quickly start assessing **whether your Amazon Elastic Block Store (Amazon EBS) volumes are encrypted** or whether specific tags are applied to your resources

Pre-built rules include:

- [rds-storage-encrypted](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/rds-storage-encrypted.html)
- EBS [encrypted-volumes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/encrypted-volumes.html)

You can also [Develop Custom Rules for AWS Config](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/evaluate-config_develop-rules.html):

> You can develop custom rules and add them to AWS Config. You associate each custom rule with an **AWS Lambda function**, which contains the logic that evaluates whether your AWS resources comply with the rule.
>
> You associate this function with your rule, and the rule **invokes the function either in response to configuration changes or periodically**. The function then evaluates whether your resources comply with your rule, and sends its evaluation results to AWS Config.

Comment: That was helpful...thanks. And do we have any built in rules for below cases? 1. Unencrypted S3 object is crated and 2. S3 bucket with global access ACLs is created

Comment: Apparently not. See: [AWS Managed Config Rules](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/managed-rules-by-aws-config.html). However, you can add custom rules (see above).